# Show that a partial order on a finite set is uniquely determined by its cover relations. [Introductory Combinatorics]

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem:** Show that a partial order on a finite set is uniquely determined by its cover relations.

**My Attempt:** I am following the proof given on Page $4$, Theorem $1.4.2$ in the following [pdf](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/earnshaw/research/poset.pdf). The author mentions that the

> Since $[x, p_1] ⊆ [x, y]$,  $ [x, p_1]$ is not determined by its cover
>   relations.

I am having trouble in understanding why this implication is true. Because it could be the case that there is only one element in between $x$ and $y$ and that is $p_1$. And so, this would imply that $[x,p_1]$ can be determined by its cover relations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since he assumes $P$ is not determined by its covering relations, there exists an interval in $P$ within which no element covers another. That is, $\exists \, x,y \in P$ s.t. $\forall \, w, z \in [x,y]$ $w$ does not cover $z$. By this assumption no sub-interval of $[x,y]$ (a subposet in itself) is determined by its covering relations and hence the implication in question follows.

The crux of the proof lies in the fact that if $P$ is not determined by its covering relations, no subposet of $P$ will be determined by *its* covering relations, a consequence that the author exploits ad infinitum to reach a contradiction.